# NextAuth Session Not Populated with User Data after Successful Login (Credentials Provider)

Tags: debugging, session, jwt, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth with a CredentialsProvider and JWT session in my app. When a user logs in, the authorize callback correctly returns a user object:

```
authorize: async (credentials) => {

// find and validate user

return {
id: user._id,
email: user.email
}
}
```

However, the session callback and getSession() do not have the user data available:

```
session: (session, token) => {
console.log(session) // { user: {} }
return session
}
```

Here's the full code along with its logs:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { mongooseConnect } from "@/lib/mongoose";
import { Person } from "@/models/Person";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { encode, decode } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

async function clientPromise() {
  await mongooseConnect();
  return mongoose.connection.getClient();
}

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise()),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Email and Password",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "password", type: "password" },
      },
      jwt: { encode, decode },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        await mongooseConnect();

        const user = await Person.findOne({ email: credentials.email });

        if (
          user &&
          (await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password))
        ) {
          console.log(
            `yo, the return statement is def running ${user._id.toString()}`
          );
          // Convert the user object to a JSON string before returning it
          const userr = {
            email: user.email,
            name: user.name,
            image: user.image,
            address: user.address,
            phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
            favorites: user.favorites,
            purchaseHistory: user.purchaseHistory,
          };
          console.log("User object in authorize:", userr);
          return userr;
        } else {
          throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    jwt: true,
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user) {
      // Parse the user object from a JSON string before modifying it
      if (user) user = user;
      if (user) token.id = user.email;
      console.log("Token and user objects in jwtt:", token, user);
      return token;
    },

    async session(session, token) {
      // Log the session and token objects before modifying them
      console.log("Session and token objects in session:", session, token);
      if (!token) {
        return session;
      }

      if (session && session.user) {
        session.user.email = token.email;
      }
      // Log the session object after modifying it
      console.log("Session object in session:", session);
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

Logs:

```
User object in authorize: {
  email: 'hello@hello.com',
  name: 'oah as',
  image: undefined,
  address: 'hmmm',
  phoneNumber: '028282',
  favorites: [],
  purchaseHistory: []
}
Token and user objects in jwtt: {
  token: {
    name: 'oah as',
    email: 'hello@hello.com',
    picture: undefined,
    sub: undefined
  },
  user: {
    email: 'hello@hello.com',
    name: 'oah as',
    image: undefined,
    address: 'hmmm',
    phoneNumber: '028282',
    favorites: [],
    purchaseHistory: []
  },
  account: {
    providerAccountId: undefined,
    type: 'credentials',
    provider: 'credentials'
  },
  isNewUser: false,
  trigger: 'signIn'
} undefined
undefined
Token and user objects in jwtt: {
  token: {
    token: { name: 'oah as', email: 'hello@hello.com' },
    user: {
      email: 'hello@hello.com',
      name: 'oah as',
      address: 'hmmm',
      phoneNumber: '028282',
      favorites: [],
      purchaseHistory: []
    },
    account: { type: 'credentials', provider: 'credentials' },
    isNewUser: false,
    trigger: 'signIn',
    iat: 1701772578,
    exp: 1704364578,
    jti: 'fafb5b4d-4488-4140-9dae-364946425fe3'
  },
  session: undefined
} undefined
Session and token objects in session: {
  session: {
    user: { name: undefined, email: undefined, image: undefined },
    expires: '2024-01-04T10:36:21.371Z'
  },
  token: {
    token: {
      token: [Object],
      user: [Object],
      account: [Object],
      isNewUser: false,
      trigger: 'signIn',
      iat: 1701772578,
      exp: 1704364578,
      jti: 'fafb5b4d-4488-4140-9dae-364946425fe3'
    },
    session: undefined
  }
} undefined
```

I have tried:

- Serializing the user object to JSON before returning in authorize callback
- Adding delays before returning session
- Implementing custom JWT encoding/decoding
- Using an adapter for session handling
- Manually assigning user properties in session callback

But none have resolved the issue.

The user data seems to be dropped between the authorize and session callbacks.

Any ideas what could be going wrong here or how I can further debug why the user object is not populating the session?

Things I have verified:

- Logging shows user data in authorize callback
- JWT and session callbacks are running

Any help or insights appreciated!